# Is there a bluetooth 5 usb device that works on a 2013 MacBook Pro Retina?

Tags: bluetooth, network-adapter, bluetooth-5, bluetooth-adapter

I need BT5 for my earbuds. I wasn't able to find an appropriate replacement of the internal networking adapter, so, now I'm hoping that somebody has a good experience with a USB BT5 adapter in an older MacBook Pro Retina.

Comment: Bluetooth 5 is backwards compatible with Bluetooth 4; is there a particular Bluetooth 5 feature you're looking for?

Comment: @JMY1000 i guess throughput. The codec changes to that old crappy one when using the earbuds microphone.

Comment: Unfortunately despite the increased bandwidth of Bluetooth 5, A2DP (which AFAIK is the only profile with widespread mic support as it contains the "headset" mode) can't take advantage of it; you'll still get the crappy audio quality.

Comment: The profile can’t take advantage of what? I got a friend with the same earbuds, newer Mac, they work perfectly.

Comment: The increased bandwidth. I just verified with a set of Airpod Pros and a 2019 tMBP that the the mic can only operate in A2DP (headset) mode. Unless your earbuds have proprietary drivers, you won't be able to use the mic and listen to audio in high quality at the same time.

Comment: Not sure what they got. They are Samsung Galaxy Buds+ and work perfectly on a newer Mac. That’s why I’m looking for a newer Bluetooth card.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/115899/discussion-between-jmy1000-and-daniel-birowsky-popeski).